# Remove an orphaned sys.service_queue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

I have an orphaned entry in my `sys.service_queues` table.

When I do

```
select * from sys.service_queues where name like '%SqlQueryNotificationService-%'
select * from sys.objects where name like '%SqlQueryNotificationService-%'
```

I see matching results:

```
SqlQueryNotificationService-1d50f684-cb16-4feb-a2e1-d53872cd1e23    627637429   NULL    6   0   SQ  SERVICE_QUEUE   2013-07-10 14:11:14.520 2013-07-10 14:11:14.520 0   0   0   1   [cqs_web].[SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure-1d50f684-cb16-4feb-a2e1-d53872cd1e23]    -2  1   1   1   0   1
SqlQueryNotificationService-1d50f684-cb16-4feb-a2e1-d53872cd1e23    627637429   NULL    6   0   SQ  SERVICE_QUEUE   2013-07-10 14:11:14.520 2013-07-10 14:11:14.520 0   0   0
```

So I'm trying to remove the orphans with:

```
DECLARE @ObjName nvarchar(max) 
DECLARE @Msg nvarchar(max) 
select @ObjName = name from sys.objects where name like 'SqlQueryNotificationService%' 
IF (@ObjName like 'SqlQueryNotificationService-%') 
BEGIN 
  print 'Found a orphan ' + @ObjName + ', checking for conversations'
  DECLARE @ConvHandle uniqueidentifier 
  DECLARE Conv CURSOR FOR 
  SELECT conversation_handle FROM sys.conversation_endpoints WITH (nolock) WHERE far_service = @ObjName; 
  OPEN Conv; 
    FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle; 
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN 
      print N'    Closing a conversation ' + CAST(@ConvHandle AS nvarchar)
      END CONVERSATION @ConvHandle WITH CLEANUP; 
      FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle; 
    END 
  CLOSE Conv; 
  DEALLOCATE Conv;

  DECLARE @count int;
  SELECT @count=COUNT(*) FROM sys.services WHERE name = @ObjName
  IF (@count > 0) BEGIN
    print '    Dropping service ' + @ObjName
    DECLARE @query as nvarchar(200);
    SET @query = N'drop service ' + @ObjName;
    EXEC sp_executesql @query
  END
END
GO

KILL QUERY NOTIFICATION SUBSCRIPTION ALL 
GO
```

But that's not clearing them out. How can I clear out my orphans?